# How can I tell meson in which directories to look for dependencies?

Tags: c++, cmake, conda, build-system, meson-build

I am coming from `CMake` to `meson`.
I like to work in isolated environments using `conda`. This way I can control which packages are installed for each project.

Now, In `cmake` I would pass `-DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=$CONDA_PREFIX` in order to root the search process on a different directory (In my case - the conda env)

So my question is how do I do achieve the same effect on `meson`?

This is my small `meson.build` for reference:

```py
project('foo', 'cpp')

cpp = meson.get_compiler('cpp')
spdlog = cpp.find_library('spdlog')

executable('foo',
  'src/fact.cpp',
  dependencies : [spdlog])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`meson` is smart enough to find packages inside conda env, assuming that you have `pkg-config` or `cmake` installed in said env.

Also - the correct way to add external dependency is using `dependency('spdlog')` and not `find_library`.

So the fixed `meson.build` should look like:

```py
project('foo', 'cpp')

spdlog = dependency('spdlog')

executable('foo',
  'src/fact.cpp',
  dependencies : [spdlog])
```

Comment: Should be noted this won't work for every `conda` package, because some package doesn't provide a  `.pc` file.

Answer (score 1):

meson receives the parameter

```
--pkg-config-path path
```

which will add *path* to the pkg-config search path.

Adding

```
spdlog = dependency('spdlog')
```

Will find spdlog as long as the .pc file is in *path*